# In inverse functions, why do we also switch the domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I know it works, but I'm trying to make sense of why the domain variable is also swapped. I know that one-to-one functions have to pass the horizontal test and I know that in order to do that, with some functions, you have to specify a domain. For example, for the function $y = x^2$ in order to ensure that the inverse function is a function, we have to limit the domain to be something like $x > 0$

Here is the text:

[image]

As you can see, the inverse function limits $y \le 0$. But why? How was this more formally established?

Comment: Because it is the natural thing to consider: if $f$ "goes" from $A$ to $B$, $f^{-1}$ "goes" from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: ohh6moreletters

Answer (score 0):

If $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ is injective, its inverse will be a function from $f(A)$ into $A$.

In the given example, $f$ is a function from $(-\infty,0]$ into $\mathbb R$. Besides, the image of $f$ is $[0,+\infty)$. Therefore, the inverse is a map from $[0,+\infty)$ onto $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear, the x is from $(-\infty, 0$ right? And the image besides domain is from $[0, \infty)$.  What do you mean it maps from $[0, \infty)$ onto $(-\infty, 0]$

Comment: @Jwan622 I don't know what is it that you mean by “image besides domain”. And what I wrote is that $f^{-1}$ is a map from $[0,+\infty)$ onto $(-\infty,0]$. THis means that the domain is $[0,+\infty)$ and that its range is $(-\infty,0]$.